# Create a Googlelike's input in CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have to recreate an `input` like the Google Material Theme one.

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

I know framework/librairies do it but it's a homework and I have to do it entirely.

Here is my actual code :

```css
input {
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px #00ffb3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <label for="text">Message</label>
  <input class="Message" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Etienne. I see you shared the basic HTML markup, but what have you tried so far? It might be worthwhile to check out what these frameworks do to create such an effect. To give you a head start: position the label either static or absolute depending on whether the input has focus (using `input:focus`). Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

You would need to absolutely position your label:

```css
.input {
  margin-top: 5px
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px #00ffb3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <label for="text">Message</label>
  <input class="Message" type="text">
</div>
```

You might want to finetune that approach a bit, but it should give you a rough idea on how to start. If that is a concern, be careful with the resposiveness of this approach as it uses fixed pixel margins that might not be fitting on e.g. a mobile phone.

Comment: Thanks a lot empiric ! You save me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer empiric gave is works and it's as you requested. However you can ofcourse tune it a bit with some animations:

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .input {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #6200EE;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.input-wrapper .input:focus+.label {
  top: -5px;
  left: 8px;
}

.input-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #6200EE;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="text" id="username">
  <label class="label" for="username">Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<fieldset>` element provides similar style, a little bit of styling to change colors is enough to get what you want. In the example below I didn't style the input, but you could do this yourself.

Example:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  color: lime;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Message:</legend>
  <input class="Message" type="text">
</fieldset>
```